# How to create a readable List<string> output?

Tags: c#

My code is as follows:

```
public List<string> connect(String query_physician, String query_institution)
{ 
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=""link""\:\s"")[^""]*(?="")");
    MatchCollection linkMatches = pattern.Matches(customSearchResult);            
    var list = new List<string>();
    list = linkMatches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList(); //put the links into a list?!            

    foreach (var item in list) //take each item (link) out of the list...
    {                
        return item; // ...and return it?! //Error, because item is a string
    }

    return null;
}
```

Like you see, I want to return each link (as a **readable list** of my json result and display it in my `RichTextBox`, but I know, `var item` is a `string`. Otherwise it doesn´t work. Either I become an unreadable list, or a string (with `string.Join(.....Cast<>())`.

Do I have this right, `string.Join(.....Cast<>())` adds the single strings together? Still, I don't want them together. Anyway, do you know a way to solve this problem?

By the way, `return null` is only a wildcard.

Comment: What do you mean by "readable list"? Do you just want to create a single string containing all the links?

Comment: If you change your return type to `IEnumerable<string>` you can use `yield return`.

Comment: I believe that "yield return" is what you need, like Kendall just mentioned.

Comment: `yield return` would be useless. She could just return the value of `list`

Comment: I see no indication that `yield return` is required here. The OP can just return `list` - that *is* the `List<string>`. It sounds like the issue is in formatting, and we have no idea how any formatting is being done here.

Comment: @Kendall Frey Oh! I've never heard about "yield return". Thank you all, for your quick reply! I'll try it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it is continuation of your previous question. Assuming you have this function (I simplified it a bit):

```
public List<string> connect(String query_physician, String query_institution)
{
    ...
    return Regex.Matches(customSearchResult, @"(?<=""link""\:\s"")[^""]*(?="")")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => m.Value)
                .ToList();
}
```

You can do the following:

```
List<string> list = connect("", "");
string linksFormatted = string.Join(",", list);
```

To show the content in RichTextBox:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's a continuation of my previous question. But, as I mentioned, I don't want to put the strings together with "string.Join()", if I understand aright, that "string.Join()" really put the strings in the list together. I want individual strings in the list, not one big string? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Valeria You already have the list of separate strings returned from the method. In your code you just need to do `return list;` right after you did `list = linkMatches...`.

Comment: My output (in the debug) is then: "list | Count = 10". That's right, I really have limited my output onto 10. But I want the strings. Like for example (in the debug): "list | "http://www.something.com" And this link "http://www.something.com" is one item of the list...

Comment: @Valeria Do you mean that you want to see the content of the list in watch window? Doesn't list expanding suit you? You can add custom expression to watch window: open 'Watch 1' window, double click on empty-cell under 'Name' column, enter `string.Join(",", list)` there.

Answer (score -2):

Look at your method signature return type is List of string no string,

so much simplest approach:

```
public List<string> connect(String query_physician, String query_institution)
{ ...

    //restults container
    List<string> resultContainer = new List<String>(); 

    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=""link""\:\s"")[^""]*(?="")");
    MatchCollection linkMatches = pattern.Matches(customSearchResult);

    var list = new List<string>();
    list = linkMatches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList(); //put the links into a list?!

    foreach (var item in list) //take each item (link) out of the list...
    {
        //add item to list
        resultContainer.Add(item); 
    }
    return resultContainer;
```

}

Comment: What's the use of copying one `List<string>` to another?

Comment: Right, i did not understood correctly. I mean just return list in above example and use returned value to place in RichTextBox